# How to substitute ng-repeat and ng-include of AngularJS to Angular 8?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, angular8, angular-hybrid

I was wondering how can I substitute doing something like this from AngularJS to Angular:

```
<li ng-repeat="node in ctrl.nodeTree" ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
```

I have been trying to do this, but I am not sure it is the right way as it not working and Angular is not complaining.

```
                    <li *ngFor="let node of nodeTree">
                        <nodes-renderer></nodes-renderer>
                    </li>
```

So I am trying to make my own custom tag from nodes_renderer.html but I want some input on which way would be better to achieve this.

**It is important to mention that my "< li >" tag is being used inside another custom "component" element tag that I have created only with css (so it doesn't have a template) in a Hybrid AngularJS-Angular app, where I am downgrading Angular components.**

Comment: as far as `nodes-renderer` is a component it should work

Comment: Ng-include doesn’t really exist in Angular..

Comment: I am aware it doesn't exist in Angular so that is why I am looking for a workaround of not having Ng-include